# Bootstrap: responsive panel and image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In my page i have a panel and 2 images, i set these classes responsive but it doesn't work.
This is my code:

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/436Qz/7/)

How can I fix it?

**EDIT :**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you have set `profile-image` class with `width:1000px`

If you set the css with a hardcode value, no way it can behave as a responsive layout as you have not provided it under any `media-query`

I removed `width:1000px` and it  [seems to work fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/436Qz/8/)

```
.profile-image{
    margin: 50px auto !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    position: relative;
   /* notice that "width" has been removed*/
}
```

If you insist on using `width:1000px`, wrap it under media-query:

```
  @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 1224px) {
      .profile-image{
        margin: 50px auto !important;
        text-align: center !important;
        width: 1000px;
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/436Qz/9/)

**EDIT**

Panel is not working because of your rule in custom css

```
.person-info{
    float: right;
    margin: -40px 71px -40px auto; /* this wrapper here is 
                                  pushing it 40px left of
                                   screen and hence responsiveness is lost totally */
    width: 808px; /* avoid fixed width without media-query*/
}
```

Remove them and then [**see it working**](http://jsfiddle.net/436Qz/10/)  *(added a red border to show the outline for demo purpose)*

Comment: why `image.png` and panel are not responsive.How can i do this?

Comment: @ElhamGdz : added the edit,please see if it helps!! :)

Comment: now i have 2 problem: 1. `image.png` is not responsive and 2. i want panel with that shape will be responsive, this panel that you set is not my goal, is there any way?

Comment: panel to be responsive is more important than is floated for me, i want panel be responsive and stay on that point that i show you in my code. i want this, is it possible?

Comment: @ElhamGdz : sure it can be achieved....just tell me where exactly you want the panel??? in your original code, it was to the left of screen with half hidden width, you want it right under the image or someplace else???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46631/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-elham-gdz)

Comment: @ElhamGdz :can you please come on chat using link above??

Comment: :sorry for yesterday, yesterday i could not answer any more. i want panel right under the image like picture that i post in my edit.

Comment: @ElhamGdz : no probs...come on chat today :)

Comment: can you come to chat?

Comment: @ElhamGdz : awaiting on chat :)